# How to Pause a VM in Hyper-V via WMI

Tags: python, powershell, wmi, hyper-v

I've got a few Hyper-VM VMs on my Windows 10 Pro Desktop.  I'd like to be able to save, pause and restart them via WMI.  My examples below are with Powershell but this is for prototyping only: my final target language is Python.  The issue I describe below happens with both Powershell and Python's WMI support.

Via Powershell's WMI support I can call Msvm_ComputerSystem.RequestStateChange.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hyperv_v2/requeststatechange-msvm-computersystem appears to list the Pausing state as 32776.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/virtual/requeststatechange-msvm-computersystem appears to list the Pausing state as 32768.

Setting the state to something simple like Enabled (2) works:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $vms = get-wmiobject -namespace root\virtualization\v2 Msvm_ComputerSystem
PS C:\Windows\system32> $vms[1].RequestStateChange(3)


__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     :
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        :
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 2
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           :
Job              : \\DESKTOP-6D2EIET\root\virtualization\v2:Msvm_ConcreteJob.InstanceID="28751864-53E3-498F-B9F0-F7C06D
                   B1FA21"
ReturnValue      : 4096
PSComputerName   :
```

(4096 means the transition has started)

But setting the state to one of the documented pausing states, 32768 or 32776, returns a ReturnValue of 32775, Invalid State e.g.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $vms[1].RequestStateChange(32776)


__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     :
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        :
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 2
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           :
Job              :
ReturnValue      : 32775
PSComputerName   :
```

So: what's the correct way to pause a Hyper-V VM with WMI?

Comment: Any reason why you wouldn't use [Suspend-VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/suspend-vm?view=win10-ps)? Are you after a particular state?

Comment: I was hoping to use WMI because it was available from other languages - Powershell is a convenient prototyping tool.  Although if I have to I can shell out to Powershell...

Comment: Have you solved your problem using WMI?